# Why should we store Promise objects in variables?

Tags: javascript

Let us suppose that we've got a function that resolves a promise like below:

```
function timeoutPromise(interval) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function(){
      resolve("done");
    }, interval);
  });
};
```

and let us suppose that we call that function inside an asynchronous function in two different ways;

**slow synchornous way:**

```
async function timeTest() {
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
  await timeoutPromise(3000);
}
```

Here we simply await all three timeoutPromise() calls directly. Each subsequent one is forced to wait until the last one finished, this will result in total run time of around 9 seconds.

**and fast asynchronous way**:

```
async function timeTest() {
  const timeoutPromise1 = timeoutPromise(3000);
  const timeoutPromise2 = timeoutPromise(3000);
  const timeoutPromise3 = timeoutPromise(3000);

  await timeoutPromise1;
  await timeoutPromise2;
  await timeoutPromise3;
}
```

Here we store the three Promise objects in variables, which has the effect of setting off their associated processes all running simultaneously. This will result in total run time of around 3 seconds.

But the question is, **why storing Promise objects in variables has the effect setting off their associated processs running simultaneously**? what happens under the hood?

Comment: "*why storing Promise objects in variables has the effect setting off their associated processs running simultaneously?*' it's nothing to do with *storing* but everything to do with *execution*. Try just reading your code out loud in human terms, the first one is "wait until this finishes; wait until that finishes; wait until the third ting finishes". You only lanuch the next thing after you've waited for the previous one. The second bit of code is "start, this, that and the the third thing. Now wait for this, that, and the third thing".

Comment: In other words, the first time you say, "wait for 3 seconds. Now wait for another 3 seconds. Finally, wait for 3 seconds". The second time it's just "start 3 timers simultaneously, wait until they all show 3 seconds."

Comment: a sidefact: instead of writing all this line by line you could use `Promise.all()`

Comment: @VLAZ in human terms, from my point of view; the second still reads as 'await A and await B and await C', with the only difference that now we are calling the objects stored in variables! I don't see how that's logicaly different! 

Promises are not executed during the time of assignment for sure, and this looks like the exact same control flow to me.... what am I missing ?!

Comment: @Ifaruki thanks mate, I was aware of that. I"m just very curious about this matter.

Comment: "*Promises are not executed during the time of assignment for sure*" of course they are. They start *immediately* A promise isn't something that will be *executed* later. It's a *value* you get later, by the time you get a promise, you have something working on it, the promise just represents the future result.

Comment: `await foo(); await bar();` will only call `bar` *after* the promise returned by `foo` is resolved. `var x = foo(); var y = bar(); await x; ...` calls `bar` *before* the promise returned by `foo` is resolved. That's what makes the promises "concurrent". If you add `console.log` in various places you will see the difference in execution.

Comment: The only difference is that they are, in fact, being executed. Try to log out one of the variables. It'll show you `Promise<peding>`

Comment: I guess you are missing the basics. async/await, promises, the callback is a way to handle async tasks in js. they will begin execution immediatly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await foo();
await bar();
```

will only call `bar` (and thus create the second promise) *after* the promise returned by `foo` is resolved.

```
var x = foo();
var y = bar();
await x;
```

calls `bar` (and thus creating the second promise) *before* the promise returned by `foo` is resolved.

That's what makes the promises "concurrent". If you add `console.log` in various places you will see the difference in execution:

```js
function timeoutPromise(name, interval) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log(`Promise ${name} created.`);
    setTimeout(function(){
      console.log(`Promise ${name} resolved.`);
      resolve("done");
    }, interval);
  });
};

async function timeTest1() {
  console.log('test 1');
  await timeoutPromise(1, 3000);
  console.log('between promise 1 and 2');
  await timeoutPromise(2, 3000);
}

async function timeTest2() {
  console.log('test 2');
  const timeoutPromise1 = timeoutPromise(1, 3000);
  console.log('between promise 1 and 2');
  const timeoutPromise2 = timeoutPromise(2, 3000);

  await timeoutPromise1;
  console.log('between promise 1 and 2 with await');
  await timeoutPromise2;
}

timeTest1().then(timeTest2);
```